# How to use dompdf within Zend-Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf

I have the following code inside my controller but I can't open the pdf it produces.

```
    $html = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'></head><body>trial</body></html>";

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

It works when used outside the framework but I don't know how to check how the pdf is mangled in any way. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:

I'm using Zend Framework 1.10 and followed this tutorial

```
http://www.encapsulated.org/blog/2009/08/27/how-to-let-dompdf-and-zend-framework-play-along/
```

Comment: any errors? If not, is error display and reporting enabled at all? Anything in the logs? I assume there is no `require_once` anywhere and you didnt setup the autloader to load the DOMPDF class? Also, any reason why you are not using `Zend_PDF`?

Comment: @Gordon No errors. Error display and reporting is enabled in the configuration. I have require_once 'dompdf_config.inc.php'; $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); 
$autoloader->pushAutoloader('DOMPDF_autoload'); inside the controller. I've also included a path to the library in index.php. I need to export to other formats too so I'm trying to set it up  as html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();        
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

I disabled the layout and viewscript inside the action generating the pdf.